# Little-Oh and Big-Oh to prove property for function product

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that:

If $f = O(|x-x_0|^k)$ and $g = o(|x-x_0|^j)$ , then

$f.g(x) = O(|x-x_0|^{k+j})$,

where $f.g$ means the product of functions $f$ and $g$.

Also, notice the difference between Big Oh $O$ and Little Oh $o$. The first one means that the ratio of the the function $f$ and that of the function indicated by $O(.)$ is bounded, whereas the little oh is a stronger condition, saying that the ratio actually converges to zero (I'm just stating the definitins since I don't know if its standard terminology\notation).

Hints before a full answer would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, $(fg)(x)=o(|x-x_0|^{k+j})$ and this stronger result might be easier to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
How can you rewrite $\frac{f \cdot g}{|x-x_0|^{k+j}}$? What do you know about the product of bounded functions?

Comment: Actually it was simpler than I thought, so just checking:

$$
\frac{f \cdot g}{|x-x_0|^{k+j}} = \frac{f}{|x-x_0|^k}.\frac{g}{|x-x_0|^j}$$

Now take, $\epsilon_1$ so that the $f$ fraction is bounded by $c$, then take $\delta_2$ so that $g$ fraction is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon_3}{c}$ and reach the desired result, ie:

$$
\frac{f}{|x-x_0|^k}.\frac{g}{|x-x_0|^j} < c.\frac{\epsilon_3}{c} < \epsilon_3$$

Am I missing some detail or technicality?

Comment: Nope, just what I meant. :) You have rewritten $\frac{f \cdot g}{|x-x_0|^{k+1}}$ and used the property of bounded functions. Well done!